# How to check if alarm does not have a pending intent?

Tags: android, android-alarms

After I call `schedulePing` my alarm fires at set time period. With `pingScheduled` I can see if pending intent exists. However, if I cancel the alarm with `cancelPing` the `pingScheduled` still return true.

```
  fun schedulePing(context: Context) {
    val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context, EventReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = EventReceiver.PING
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, PING, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    val s = SettingsUtil.load(context)
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + s.periodPing, s.periodPing,
        pendingIntent)
  }

  fun cancelPing(context: Context) {
    if (pingScheduled(context).not()) return
    val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context, EventReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = EventReceiver.PING
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, PING, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    am.cancel(pendingIntent)

  }

  fun pingScheduled(context: Context): Boolean {
    val intent = Intent(context, EventReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = EventReceiver.PING
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, PING,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`am.cancel(pendingIntent)` cancel alram, but does not discard the pending intent. So it is important to call 
`pendingIntent.cancel` after `am.cancel` to be able to check correct presence with `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`